# How to set for all the new pages new Experience View

Tags: new-experience

How could I set for all the pages new Expeience for all the pages and all the list in Sharepoint Sites and Subsites ? I have set in settings, but not all pages changes for New Experience View.

**Edited Added**

I have got only 
Site Wiki and Site Web Part
Not Site Page
[image]

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online? How long have you been waiting after changing the setting? In our environment disabling new experience needed some time to complete (maybe 1 h).

Comment: Yes I use Sharepoint Online. It was changed abaut 3 months ago and still is Clasic View all pages created before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only **Modern Site Pages** will be having the new experience, not the other Pages like wiki, web-part pages.
So any other existing pages of other 'types' will still be available in classic mode only.

[image]

**Edit1:** You can set the modern experience at tenant level as well. Do check out this [**blog**](http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/11/3-places-manage-modern-classic-experience-lists-libraries/) for reference

**Edit 2:**
Add the Site Page content type to the Pages Library. Library Settings --> Add from Existing Content type --> Under Document Content type group, select 'Site Page' --> Add --> OK

[image]

Comment: But I have got only: List, Document Library, Aplication and Subsite, I dont see Wiki Page and Web Part Page and I don't see Link

Comment: The screen-shot attached was from "Pages" Library.. you can navigate to "Pages" and then click +new

Comment: but I have got only Wiki Page, Web Part Page and Link. Not more. Please help/

Comment: Refer my updated answer under Edit2

Comment: And which template of a Page should I use ?

Comment: Because there are a lot of site templates. So which site template Should I choose to have got a "New Experience" site template.

Comment: 1. Site template - Team site; 2. Did you enabled modern experience at various level as refer by blog in Edit 1 of my answer? ; 3. Modern Site pages doesn’t have any page templet but You can add various widgets/web parts to it

Comment: Yes I'm enebled them in Setings of Sharepoint Site Collection Sites. Is there any place to enebled them again ? Can I have at time sites upper menu ? Drill up and drill down ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79652/discussion-between-dvg-and-grzegorz-z).